# Text area field is not taking any input and even not able to select in mobile layout

Tags: html

I'm using this `<textarea`> in my web application

```
<div class="col-xs-11 lessSpaceBetweenLine">
    <textarea class="form-control actionitems" id="actionitems"
              name="actionitems" rows="2"
              placeholder="Enter action item description"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd be guessing another element or script is interfering with it, you don't really have enough information in your question to see what's happening sorry

Comment: I'm using textarea in my web application but when I'm using that application in mobile than I'm not able to select that textarea to enter any input it's just like read only.

Comment: Have you written any scripts for the above classes and Id?

Comment: No I have never written any scripts to these classes.

Comment: Maybe there is any transparent element that overlaps textarea in narrow screen. Use chrome dev tools in device mode to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the div class from "class="col-xs-11" to class "col-sm-11"